# Replace electric connector with different type (from C13 to European)

Tags: connector, plug

By mistake I got a wrong electric appliance and due to the fact that it was shipped from US to Europe, it's not worth returning it to replace with another.

Situation: There is a motor which has a US male connector. And there is a controller for the motor that has a C13 female connector. It should have been a US female connector but by mistake it isn't. As finding a US male to C13 female adapter is difficult and takes too long to be shipped, I thought of the possibility to take it to an electrician and cut the end of the cord and replace the connector with a European female receptacle and then put a US to Europe adapter.

Will this approach work? Is there anything I should pay attention to?

Comment: That should work, but I'd rather replace the US male with a C13 male conenctor.

Comment: First check if the appliance works with 230V 50 Hz instead of 120V 60 Hz.

Comment: @Jeroen3 it does.

Comment: @Humpawumpa does the order of  the wires matter when I connect it o to a new connector?

Comment: Technically only earth matters in a AC application

Comment: @Humpawumpa I thought that perhaps the order matters since the shape of the connector forces you to have it connected only one way.

Comment: That's the case for most of the AC connectors that have an earth pin

Comment: @Andrew I suggest you read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/181070/)  and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/124215/) before doing the modification.